# can't add realm to android studio

Tags: android, realm

I added:

```
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.72.0'
```

to my dependencies

then I am getting this error:
Error:Failed to find: io.realm:realm-android:0.72.0
Open File
Open in Project Structure dialog

Comment: Error is related to your gradle file.Please post your gradle file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are missing

```
repositories {
   jcenter()
}
```

in your gradle.build.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add the class path dependency to the project level build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.0"
}
```

}

step 2: apply plugin: 'realm-android'

step 3:`realm {
  syncEnabled = true;
}`